# How to Make United States as a default value in customized picklist field

Tags: custom-field, picklist, dependent-picklist

I have created a country picklist and have made united states as a default value in picklist. I have also created a state picklist which is dependent on country field but when I create a new record,I donot see United state as a default value on the country field.How is it possible.The object has 2 record types and 8 page layout layouts.

Kindly help

Comment: Did you specify the default value for each record type?

Comment: Also, default only works via the UI if the field(s) are on the page layout. In addition,  IIRC creating records via apex/data loader/api do not honor the default value.

Comment: As @Eric stated, if you're not using the UI, you could put any value under the sun into the picklist.  Salesforce doesn't follow key constraints when loading data. I do this all the time when uploading leads.